# How to enter SVN credentials into Jenkins without using UI?

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins

When configuring a build job for the first time that uses Subversion for SCM you get an error that looks like this:

[image]

I'm aware that to enter my credentials I simply need to use this url.
http://< my-server >/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential

But I'm trying to completely automate the set up/configuration of my jenkins server. Is there a way to give jenkins svn credentials without having to access the UI?

My jenkins server is on Windows and is the latest version. Subversion is on linux.

**Edit:** I've come across a screenshot online similar to the one above except the is a **Credentials** field! **Does anyone know why I can't see this field**. Here is the url of the image
http://michal.karzynski.pl/images/illustrations/2014-04-19/jenkins-source-code-management-configuration.png

Thanks

Comment: If you build without addressing these errors you get the following error in the console output:

svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to use the Subversion command line. Jenkins doesn't need the command line client and you might have to install it.

However, for a particular repository, do a checkout of a project via the command line with the user you want to use. Then, say "Yes" when Subversion asks if you want to cache the credentials.

When Jenkins does a checkout, it will use these cached credentials if you didn't specify a particular Jenkins credential to use. This works per Subversion repository.

Comment: This seems closer to what I'm after. I've tried using svn command line to check out directly on the machine and I have tried checking out using a jenkins job directly in the execute batch command window . The checkout works fine but when I go back to the original job configuration jenkins is still displaying the error from the original Post. 



SVN did not ask me to cache the credentials though so is there something I'm not doing correctly? My command is "svn checkout https://<my-code-repo>.com/project/ --username svnuser --password svnpassword

Comment: What user is running Jenkins? That's the user you need to be logged in as. I see this is Windows, and by default, Windows uses a special service user, but that can be changed.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it will be the way forward. As a test I set jenkins to run under my user and this resolved the error. I think I will try to script in running the service as a user that has also checked out code on the machine. Will let you know how I get on. Thanks again David

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

this can provide credentials to svn repo.

what actually you gonna do? just access the SVN or looking for the SVN SCM change  or any other. simply enter password i don't forsee a need of jenkins plugin

Comment: I have this plugin already. My build jobs use svn but when you configure your first build job you get this error: Unable to access https://<my-repo>/Trunk : svn: E200015. It provides a link to http://<my-jenkins-server>/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential. Have edited my original questions to clarrify

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to create some "domain credentials" in the "Manage credentials" section (admin part: `http://<server>:8080/credentials/`):

[image]

Comment: I have also tried this already I'm afraid. It seems like the svn plugin ignores these and has it's own page for adding credentials

Comment: In your Jenkins job, in the Subversion section, did you select the relevant user in the "Credentials" combo box? (my.svn.user in my example).
We are using these settings with our private SVN branch and it works well.

Comment: I cant see this field as you can see from my screenshot. I have the latest versions of everything so not sure if this button has been removed

Comment: Ok I was wrong about the version of SVN plugin. I have updated it which now gives the credential drop down. However I cant get jenkins to automatically pick up the svn credential config. My current process is to just copy the required files so that when jenkins starts it picks up job cofig and credential config.

Comment: Cool if you can see the drop down :)
If your svn user is declare in the global credentials section, you should be able to select your user when configuring your job.
Our SVN jobs are working like that (for private svn repositories) and it's OK.

Comment: I'm still trying find a nice way of automating this so I don't need to manually configure any part of the setup. The job config.xml contains a credentials ID for the svn user but this ID is unique to each jenkins server so just copying it to a new server and running the reload config button doesn't work